# Open webpage after IDLE has completed running the script Python

Tags: python, python-idle

I have written my script in Python. After the script runs in IDLE(finishes running, i want to open a webpage(IDLE will open the webpage in the default browser) where the result will be displayed. Can this be done? If so, pls help.
Thank You

Comment: You question is unclear.  It does not seem to have anything to do with IDLE.

Answer (score 2):

It could be done, using standard python library: http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open(url[, new=0[, autoraise=True]])
```